# How to populate modals individually from input in every row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Adding new info input changes the previous modal contents.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainTable').DataTable({});
  var dataTable = $("#mainTable").dataTable().api();
  
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    lname = $('#lname').val();
    var info = $('.info').val();
    
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML = "<tr><td>" + fname + "</td><td>" + lname + "</td><td><div><button id='showInfo' class='showInfo' type='button'>&plus;</button></div></td></tr>";
    dataTable.row.add(tr);
    dataTable.draw();

    $(document).on("click", '.showInfo', function() {
      $('.modalinfo').text(info);
      $(".modal").css("display", "block");
    });
    
    $(".close").click(function() {
      $(".modal").css("display", "none");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
Result Size: 753 x 671

  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="inputlines">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="fname"></td>

        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="lname"></td>
        <td>Info:</td>
        <td><input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="info" class="info"></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <table id="mainTable">
    <thead id="myTableData">
      <tr>
        <th><b>First Name</b></th>
        <th><b>Last Name</b></th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p class="modalinfo"></p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <input type="button" id="showInfo" class='showInfo' style="display:none;">
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/averola/b4p0zu6q/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you add a new event to every pre-existing `.showInfo` element when a new one is added to the DOM. This overwrites the `info` value with the latest one for each instace.

To fix this you could add the `info` value as a `data` attribute on each new `button` you append, and this can then be read back out of the DOM in a single delegated event handler which applies to all buttons. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainTable').DataTable({});
  var dataTable = $("#mainTable").dataTable().api();

  $("#add").click(function() {
    let fname = $('#fname').val();
    let lname = $('#lname').val();
    let info = $('.info').val();
    let $tr = $(`<tr><td>${fname}</td><td>${lname}</td><td><div><button class="showInfo" type="button" data-info="${info}">&plus;</button></div></td></tr>`);

    dataTable.row.add($tr);
    dataTable.draw();
  });

  $(document).on("click", '.showInfo', function() {
    $('.modalinfo').text($(this).data('info'));
    $(".modal").css("display", "block");
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".modal").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputlines">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="fname"></td>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="lname"></td>
      <td>Info:</td>
      <td><input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="info" class="info"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<table id="mainTable">
  <thead id="myTableData">
    <tr>
      <th><b>First Name</b></th>
      <th><b>Last Name</b></th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p class="modalinfo"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="showInfo" class='showInfo' style="display:none;">
```